# Iniciante : C# função recursiva

Tags: c#, asp.net

ajuda para Função Recursiva que imprima a média dos elementos de uma lista de inteiros e o número de elementos maiores do que a média. em c#

bom, o que tenho ate o momento, está dando erro System.StackOverflowException.

```c#
public static Double MediaLista(Double[] v)
{
    int i = 0;
    Double soma = 0;
    if (i < v.Length)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < v.Length; j++)
        {
            soma += v[j];
        }
        i++;
        return soma / MediaLista(v);
    }
    else return 0;

}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Double[] v = {1,2,3,3,5};
    Double resul =  MediaLista(v);

}
```

Edit : 
incrementei a funcionalidade de pegar os números maiores que a média no próprio método MediaLista. No todo meu método ficou assim.

```
        public static double MediaLista(int[] v, int ultimo)
    {
        if (ultimo == 0)
        {

            return v[0];
        }
        else
        {

            int qtdNumero = ultimo + 1;
            double soma = v[ultimo] + (qtdNumero - 1) * MediaLista(v, ultimo - 1);
            if (qtdNumero == v.Length) {
                for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (v[i] > (soma / qtdNumero))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"o numero {v[i]}  é maior que a média");
                    }
                }
            }

            return soma / qtdNumero;


        }

    }
```

Comment: Por favor adicione o código na sua pergunta.

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Dê uma olhada no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) do site para umas dicas de como formular a pergunta e faça algumas alterações nela, pois da forma que está dá a impressão que você está querendo que alguém faça pra você ao invés de te ajudar.

Comment: opa, adicionado

Comment: Provavelmente está sobrando fechamento de chaves.

Comment: esta em loop, assim como o @RonaldoAraújoAlves disse...

Comment: return soma / MediaLista(v); o return da soma = 0 / 0 = estouro. Pega sua calculadora aí e divide 0 / 0. Tu vai ter valor indefinido ou no c# stackoverflow pq no if tá lá que se i < v vai pro loop, se o i = 0 entao nunca vai terminar isso.

Comment: Dividir algum número por 0 dá [DivideByZeroException](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dividebyzeroexception?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Meeeeu Deus, não acredito que eu dei essa gafe kkkk, certo. Mas não entendi o motivo dela ser recursiva. A idéia é calcular a media dessa lista de elementos e mostrar os que estão acima dessa media ponto. Pra que chamar denovo? A próxima chamada é pra calcular quais estão acima da media e parar aí a recursividade?

Comment: É um exercício de lógica pelo que entendi. A ideia não é o resultado, é o treino

Comment: Pois é, como eu tbm sou iniciante em c# (vim do vb.net) to quebrando a cabeça aqui pq nunca tinha usado recursividade, mas consegui fazer  até a media, falta pegar quais elementos são maiores q a media.

Comment: Legal @VanderleiJunior , peguei a sua logica para pegar os numeros maiores que a média e incrementei no método da média. Isso nao deve alterar na recursividade da função.

Answer (score 1):

`StackOverflowException` ocorre quando há um **transbordamento** da memória Stack, geralmente causado por excesso de funções aninhadas.

No caso na linha `return soma / MediaLista(v);` você não alterou nada o vetor `v`, fazendo com que chame o método novamente, e novamente, e novamente.....até causar essa exceção. :)

Acredito que o que esteja querendo fazer é `return soma / v.Length;`

---

**EDIT**

Há outro erro, dessa vez de lógica.

Na linha `soma += v[i];` você está fazendo loop com o `j` mas somando o íncide `i`, que é sempre 0.

---

**EDIT 2.0 - Recursividade Edition :P**

Aparentemente está ok. :)

```c#
public static void Main()
{
    int[] v = { 1, 2, 9, 10, 25, 0};
    double media = Media(v, v.Length - 1);
    Console.Write(media);
}

public static double Media(int[] v, int ultimo)
{
    if (ultimo == 0)
        return v[0];

    int qtdNumero = ultimo+1;       
    double soma = v[ultimo] + (qtdNumero-1) * Media(v, ultimo-1);

    return soma/qtdNumero;
}
```

Comment: sim, porem com o ' return soma / v.Length; ', faz dela uma função não recursiva correto?

Comment: Certo. Esqueci da necessidade de ser recursiva. Pera que vou precisar reformular a resposta.

Comment: @ArlindoCruzMachado editei a resposta com o código

Answer (score 0):

Assim eu consegui fazer a recursividade tirando o for e usando if e ao invez de incrementar eu fui decrementando pra recursividade chegar no 0 e sair do loop e me dar o resultado:

EDIT: acrescentei a parte que pega quais elementos são maiores do que a média

```
    private void MetroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double[] v = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 5 };
        double resul = MediaLista(v, v.Length, 0);
        //Elementos da array maiores do que a média
        string maiorMedia = string.Empty;
        for (int i = v.GetLowerBound(0); i <= v.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            if (v[i] > resul)
            {
                maiorMedia += v[i] + ",";                    
            }
        }
        metroLabel3.Text = Convert.ToString(resul);
        metroLabel4.Text = maiorMedia;

    }
    //média dos elementos de uma lista de inteiros
    public double MediaLista(double[] v, int tamanho, double media)
    {
        if (tamanho > 0)
        {                
            media = v[tamanho - 1] + MediaLista(v, tamanho - 1, media);
            if (tamanho == v.Length)
            {
                return media / v.Length;
            }
            return media;
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }
```

EDIT2:

Só pra brincar mais um pouco a parte que pega quais elementos da array são maiores do que a média, eu fiz mais uma opção em LINQ pra quem quiser entender esse recurso que é muito usado no Entity Framework e outros ORM

```
        string maiorQueMedia = string.Empty;
        var query =
            from num in v
            where num > resul
            select num;
        foreach (double num in query)
            maiorQueMedia += num + ",";
```